# Can you define C++ methods in a reopened class environment, rather than by prefixing with the class name?

Tags: c++, class, syntax

In every lesson and book on C++ I've ever seen, a class has been written like this:

*header.h*

```cpp
class MyClass
{
   ...
   int myMethod(int my_para);
};
```

*source.cpp*

```cpp
...
int
MyClass::myMethod(int my_para)
{
   ...
}
```

But I do find that the `MyClass::` just adds to the natural chaos and bewilderment of C++, especially when `MyClass` is actually more like `MySomethingSomethingCreator`. I would like to write my class definitions in more of a namespace style, like this:

*header.h*

```cpp
class MyClass
{
   ...
   int myMethod(int my_para);
};
```

*source.cpp*

```cpp
class MyClass
{
   ...
   int myMethod(int my_para)
   {
      ...
   }
}
```

Now, I know from trying that doing exactly this does not work, but is there a way to do something similar - just to remove a little of the noise? I am not interested in defining functions actually inside the class declaration - that's the work of the devil!

Comment: `using C = MySomethingSomethingCreator;`

Comment: Inline member functions in a header file are not the work of the devil.  Preprocessor macros are the work of the devil.

Comment: *just to remove a little of the noise?* -- I could understand if the issue had to do with multiple names, for example. `std::map<std::pair<int, int>, std::vector<std::pair<double, double>>>::const_iterator`, but it was you or your fellow programmers who decided to use the single long name of `MySomething...`.  C++ isn't at fault there.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Wise man he say: There isn't a single problem in the whole of computer science that can't be solved by an additional level of indirection.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Well, that's not just C++ - it's OOP - but it is a fault. It absolutely does encourage the creation of structures with weird extended names. It's nice that we can use class hierarchies and namespaces to reduce this a bit, but I still see these weird names over and over again in OO code.

I don't want to take away from the horror of your example though.

Answer (score 2):

> but is there a way to do something similar

No.

> MyClass:: just adds to the natural chaos and bewilderment of C++

It's just one of the little things that a new C++ programmer has to learn to accept. Once you get used to it, it will no longer be bewildering.

Comment: I am not a deeply experienced C++ programmer, but I am not new either. I've been writing admittedly quite basic C++ since the late 90s, and its hideous and confusing syntax and extreme verbosity has always been a problem for me. And for many other people too.

I just thought that maybe there was something here that lots of people had missed. These things happen.

Answer (score 1):

> MyClass:: just adds to the natural chaos and bewilderment of C++

I wouldn't agree with you. Imagine you are working with a huge code database, and you come across a definition of a function in `.cpp` file like this.

```
.
.
.
.
    int myfunc(std::string some_arg)
    {
        //whatever can be here    
    }
.
.
.
.
.
```

And now you would wonder, is this a function in a namespace or method of some class. Of course the class specifier you suggested would appear above, but in can be thousand of lines above, or even 10 thousands, which one probably wouldn't want to deal with. Someone would like to know if it is a method or function by directly looking on it.

The `MyClass::` specifier serves greatly for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. This is generally not a problem, though. In fact, there is good reason to want to do this with free functions. John Lakos points out in *Large-Scale C++ Volume I* (2020) p. 155–156, you can (and may want to) do this:

```
// foo.h
namespace my_product {

int foo(int);

} // namespace my_product
```

then

```
// foo.cpp
#include <my_product/foo.h>

int my_product::foo(int x) {
    return x * 2;
}
```

The advantage of this is: suppose you want to change the signature to take `float` and you change it in the `.cpp` to `float my_product::foo(float x)`. If done this way, `float my_product::foo(float x)` can *only* define the function, it can't declare it, so you'd get a compile error: https://godbolt.org/z/eGbv3rTx5

```
error: out-of-line definition of 'foo' does not match any declaration in namespace 'my_product'
float my_product::foo(float x) {
                  ^~~
```

whereas if your .cpp file is

```
// foo.cpp
#include <my_product/foo.h>

namespace my_product {

float foo(float x) {
    return x * 2;
}

} // namespace my_product
```

and you try to use the function, you have to wait for the whole project to build and then get a link error: https://godbolt.org/z/soo7r97fG

```
undefined reference to `my_product::foo(int)'
```

I've started to get in this habit of defining functions like this so I can have immediate compile errors rather than waiting for a potentially big build only to get a link error, which then requires fixing the header (hopefully correctly!) and then waiting *again* for a big rebuild.